# Enforcing case constraint on textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have a textbox with the case settings from the database. If the database setting is Upper Case then the textbox text should be converted to Upper Case and if the Setting is Proper Case then the textbox text should be converted to Proper Case. I have achieved this with the help of javascript.

However, I have one more setting which is Upper Changeable where the textbox text is converted to upper case. But if the user does not want upper case he can change the case.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function toUpper(obj) {
       var mystring = obj.value;
       var sp = mystring.split(' ');
       var wl = 0;
       var f, f1, f2, r1, r2, r;
        if (document.getElementById('<%= hdnNameStyle.ClientID %>').value == "UC") {
         mystring = mystring.toUpperCase();
         obj.value = mystring;
     }
     if (document.getElementById('<%= hdnNameStyle.ClientID %>').value == "PC") {
         var word = new Array();
         for (i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
             f = sp[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
             r = sp[i].substring(1);
             word[i] = f + r;
         }
         newstring = word.join(' ');
         obj.value = newstring;
     }
     if (document.getElementById('<%= hdnNameStyle.ClientID %>').value == "UG") {
         mystring = mystring.toUpperCase();
         obj.value = mystring;
     }
  }
```

This is the javascript that I have tried and it works fine. However, to clarify it further if the hdnNameStyle value is UG the textbox text is converted to uppercase, but if the user does not want uppercase he can change the case.

How to enable the user to change the case with the help of javascript?

Thanks,

Comment: Hey that was really interesting question but will be really thankful for you if you post some code that you have done till now.

Comment: @asifa You should have a look at CSS and `text-transform` ;)

Comment: @Andreas i have set that when the setting is UC that is upper compulsory the user cannot change the case, but when the setting is UG the user can change the case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the text itself, just use CSS classes for it.

```
/* css */
.uppercase { text-decoration: uppercase }
.propercase { text-decoration: capitalize }


<!-- html -->
<p id="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleUppercase()" />


// javascript
function toggleUppercase() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (text.className === "uppercase") {
        text.className = "propercase";
    } else {
        text.className = "uppercase";
    }
}
```

With this you should be able get a working solution.